# How to use JOIN in INSERT INTO SELECT but create condition when matching the columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables, **staging**, **positions_mapping**, and **target**.

**staging** table

| id | pos_name |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | SM |
| 5 | Agile Scrum Master |
| 6 | Scrum Master |

**positions_mapping** table

| id | position_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Agile Scrum Master |

And on the **target table** I intend to insert those rows from staging like this:

| id | position_id |
| --- | --- |
| 14 | 1 |
| 15 | 1 |
| 16 | 1 |

At first I do this by using JOINS:

```
INSERT INTO target(position_id)
SELECT positions_mapping.id FROM staging
LEFT JOIN positions_mapping ON positions_mapping.position_name = staging.pos_name
```

But that works for an exact match only. Different names for Agile Scrum Master came and I still need to insert those as **"Agile Scrum Master"** regardless if it's an exact match or not.

I'm thinking of having conditional statements here? I'm not so sure where to place them.

Comment: Do you have a list of what the alternate names are? If it's only the examples above (and I'm understanding correctly), you could do something like `positions_mapping.position_name = CASE WHEN staging.pos_name IN ('SM', 'Scrum Master') then 'Agile Scrum Master' ELSE staging.pos_name END` in your `join` condition.

Comment: hello. There are still other positions, not just the Agile Scrum Master, I just used one position for simplicity. Let me try your example. Actually I kind of thinking something like that, CASE and IN but I'm getting syntax errors whenever I try 

Comment: Please provide the code you're trying that causes the syntax error.

Comment: @EdmCoff, I'm okay with your solution. I got it to work now.  You can post your answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your `ON` clause. Something like:

```
positions_mapping.position_name = CASE WHEN staging.pos_name IN ('SM', 'Scrum Master') then 'Agile Scrum Master' ELSE staging.pos_name END
```

This does require hardcoding all of your special cases, but unless you have a mapping somewhere or a reliable pattern for conversion, you will almost certainly have to do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Wizh a full zexz search you could fond two of the rows but the first is to generic to find it.

But as you can't ppu any column of another table you need a dynamic approach

> ```
> CREATE TABLE staging (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `pos_name` VARCHAR(18),
>    FULLTEXT KEY (pos_name )
> );
>
> INSERT INTO staging
>   (`id`, `pos_name`)
> VALUES
>   ('4', 'SM'),
>   ('5', 'Agile Scrum Master'),
>   ('6', 'Scrum Master');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE positions_mapping (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `position_name` VARCHAR(18)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO positions_mapping
>   (`id`, `position_name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'Agile Scrum Master');
> ```

> ```
> PREPARE stat FROM "SELECT s.`id`,pm.`id` 
> FROM staging s JOIN positions_mapping pm ON MATCH (s.`pos_name` ) AGAINST (?) > 0";
> SET @c_val = (SELECT `position_name` FROM positions_mapping WHERE  `position_name` = 'Agile Scrum Master');
> EXECUTE stat USING @c_val;
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> id | id
> -: | -:
>  5 |  1
>  6 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2d44acc6287fa55deceb51d19d8b927b)*